# PMD/Checkstyle Analyzer for properties

Tags: translation, checkstyle, properties-file, pmd, analyzer

For our translation keys (base*.properties) we have a strict syntax that looks like

```
{page}.({step}.){typecode}.({sub-typecode}.){name}=Lorem ipsum ...
```

whereas `page`, `typecode` and `name` are mandatory. `step` and `sub-typecode` are optional.

Example:

- checkout.delivery.label.address (checkout is the `page`, delivery is the `step` of the page, label is the `typecode` and adress is the `name`)

The problem is that we have many developers / consultants and during our internal code review we are always facing some violations which doesn't follow the key syntax. To be more productive I would like to have an analyzer like PMD / Checkstyle - but this time for checking the keys in selected properties files which are considered for translation.

Is such analyzer available somewhere? It is possible with PMD / Checkstyle? If yes, how?

Thank you,
Christoph

p.s.
I already tried with (maybe I'm doing it wrongly?) http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#RegexpMultiline
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#Translation